# How do I display something only if there are results in the array from a query?

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop, echo

How would I rewrite this code to only display the `<h3>` tag only if there are results returned from the query?

I am very new to PHP, I know this can be done, I'm just not sure of the best method.

Any help I could get would be great.

Thank you in advance.

My current code is as follows.

```
<h3 class="state" name="art">Art</h3>
<?php
    if (mysql_error() > "") print mysql_error() . "<br>";
    mysql_select_db($database_name, $db);
    if (mysql_error() > "") print mysql_error() . "<br>";
      $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member_page WHERE community_id = $cityid AND category=1 ORDER BY entity_name");

        echo "";
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))

      {
          echo "<div id='result'><div id='entity_name'><h4>".$row['entity_name']."</h4></div><img width='275' height='170' src='images/".$row['id']."/coverphoto/".$row['cp_path']."' ><div id='searchblurb'><p>".$row['search_blurb']."</p></div><a border='0' href='member-info.php?id=".$row['id']."' onMouseOut='MM_swapImgRestore()' onMouseOver='MM_swapImage('go','','images/custom/go-over.png',1)'><img src='images/custom/go-out.png' alt='Visit this community' width='120' height='40' id='go' border='none'></a> 
        </div>";
      }
      echo "";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try some thing like this:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($query) != 0)
{
    echo "<h3 class='state' name='art'>Art</h3>";
}
```

Please also take note that `mysql_* functions` are depreciated try to learn  **[PDO HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)**

---

**UPDATE**

Im not sure if this is what you wanted but you can try this:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($query) != 0)
{
    echo "<h3 class='state' name='art'>Art</h3>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo "<div id='result'><div id='entity_name'><h4>".$row['entity_name']."</h4></div><img width='275' height='170' src='images/".$row['id']."/coverphoto/".$row['cp_path']."' ><div id='searchblurb'><p>".$row['search_blurb']."</p></div><a border='0' href='member-info.php?id=".$row['id']."' onMouseOut='MM_swapImgRestore()' onMouseOver='MM_swapImage('go','','images/custom/go-over.png',1)'><img src='images/custom/go-out.png' alt='Visit this community' width='120' height='40' id='go' border='none'></a> 
    </div>";
  }
}
```